# Testing a class

Tags: java, android, testing

I am trying to test the class by making a program. I don't really understand how to. All I know is that it has something to do with prime numbers, but that is all I know. Can someone please help me? I would really appreciate it if you do. Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Android
{
  public static int tag = 1; 
  private String name;
  public static int n = 0;
  Android ()
  {
    name = "Bob";
    changeTag();
  }

  String getName(Object input)
  {
    return input.getClass().getName();
  }

  private static boolean isPrime(int n)
  {
    for(int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
      if (n % i == 0)
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  public static void changeTag()
  {
    do
    {
      tag++;
    } while (!isPrime(n));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There will be a class that contains the `main method`. (Assume MainClass the name of the class.)

Main class looks like:

```
public MainClass{
   public static void main(String args[]){
      /*Source Code*/
   }
}
```

And you can make `Android` object in main method. Like this:

```
Android android = new Android();
```

And then, JVM (Java Virtual Machine) will run the `Android` constructor for `Android` class. Depending on Android constructor, the JVM will run `changeTag()` method. And `changeTag()` method finds the Prime by increasing the `tag` variable.

If you want to verify the prime, use follow this code:

```
System.out.println("prime"+tag);
```

You can see that the prime(tag) is output from the console window.

**Full source:**

Android Class :

```
import java.util.Scanner; //You don't need because you don't use Scanner.
public class Android
{
  public static int tag = 1; 
  private String name;
  public static int n = 0;
  Android ()
  {
    name = "Bob";
    changeTag();
  }

  String getName(Object input)
  {
    return input.getClass().getName();
  }

  private static boolean isPrime(int n)
  {
    for(int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
      if (n % i == 0)
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  public static void changeTag()
  {
    do
    {
      tag++;
    } while (!isPrime(n));
    System.out.println("prime"+tag);
  }
}
```

Main Class :

```
public MainClass{
   public static void main(String args[]){
      Android android = new Android();
   }
}
```

(May be an error because I didn't run this program. Explained only on the basis of the theory.)